# How to get the IP Machine SMS ID, MAC Address, OS details of a machine through intranet web application in asp.net mvc (without activex object)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, npapi, google-nativeclient, emscripten, asm.js

**Problem:**

I am stuck up with an issue in which I have to find machine details ( OS version , OS architecture, OS Role host name, SCCM Site code, SCCM Version , IP address, MAC address).

Earlier I was doing it using activex Object in which I was deploying a dll (prepared using C++ code and using firebreath to generate the dll from ocx compiled file of C++) on client browser context using activex. Firebreath uses NPAPI. This Native Code was available to all the browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE till 10).

Now after google declared not to allow NPAPI later this year will create problem.

**Looked Upon**

Since the above details I am looking for is web user details, so I was looking into **emscripten** which can generate javascript from C++ code to be executed in the browser context and could get me details, but after trying a lot I was not able to generate the javascript code from my C++ code (I am not sure why it fails when using emcc command using emscripten compiler to generate js code, it fails in finding atlbase.h)

It will be great if any one could help me out in generating JS code using emscripten or can suggest me any other route to get the above mentioned machine details using an interanet application. I don't want to use WMI route as my web application supports mac machine as well as Modern UI browsers

**Link for emscripten**- https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki

Comment: Client IP's should really be trivial to obtain as a server (Unless you want it's local IP). Any way, JavaScript doesn't have access to any of those details. Doesn't matter if you compile it from C++.

Comment: Cerbrus - Yes you are right it is not possible and accessible  to get all the above details using conventional Javascript but I am not sure about asm.js which is able to access a lot many details from conventional javascript frameworks

Comment: Emscripten generated asm.js doesn't have any special access either.

Comment: Georg- I am failed to generate the JS file using C++ code .. Can we generate JS file using emscripten from a cpp file which has MFC library used .. Any Idea ?

Comment: Emcscripten has no special access to the system, so no you can't use MFC or ATL.

Answer (score 1):

The only option that I can see that will work on Chrome is [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging); in order to get most of that I think you will have to be running native code.

You'll probably need to keep using your FireBreath plugin for all other browsers; I don't know of any other options that may work.  I guess [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes) might work on firefox.

Comment: Even my research says that for getting above mentioned details I need to use Native Messaging but even then it depends on Google to allow the extension to get the details. And the downside of extension is that every web application will be able to get the details which is vulnerable to machine

Comment: Extensions can be restricted to a specific domain; how is that less secure than NPAPI and ActiveX plugins?

Comment: yeah, have to agree with Stuart on this one. Extensions are far easier to secure than plugins are.  In addition, there literally is not another way to get what you want, other than a NPAPI plugin (which is being deprecated) or Native Messaging.  Native Messaging is definitely the more secure of the two, but it's also more painful to install since (if I understand correctly) it requires administrative privileges to install and has to be installed separately from the extension.